# Could somebody show me how to aggreggate values for a specific time span in SQL? :)

Tags: sql, date, sum, aggregation

I am trying to aggreggate the sum of costs for the top 25 participants between 2020 and 2021. Everytime that I do this, it gives me the top 25 participants by cost, but groups them by *either* 2020 or 2021 rather than aggreggating the sum.

For example, I get something like Participant 1 had cost X, Participant 2 had cost Y, Participant 3 had cost Z. When I validate these figures, I'm seeing that Participant 1 with cost X is the value from 2020, Participant 2 with cost Y is the value from 2021, Participant 3 with cost Z is the value from 2020, etc.

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong? I want to be able to see participants ranked in order of aggregate costs spanning 2020 - 2021 :)

Here is the code that I wrote:

```
select top 25
participant_ID,
SUM(cost_amount) as total_cost
from cost_table
where cost_year between '2020' AND '2021'
group by participant_ID, cost_amount
Order by cost_amount DESC
```

Comment: please add a full [mre]  with create table data and wanted result as text

Comment: And what DBMS are you using?

Comment: I'm using snowflake

Answer (score 0):

```
select top 25
participant_ID,
SUM(cost_amount) as total_cost
from cost_table
where cost_year between '2020' AND '2021'
group by participant_ID
Order by 2 DESC
```

You have to use ORDER BY sum(cost_amount) DESC, not by the cost. It is not clear why do you group additionally by cost_amount if you want to sum it.